# Prove that n is a prime number if and only if $(n−2)! \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Prove that $n$ is a prime number if and only if $(n−2)! \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

I proved the part where we suppose that the latter is true and prove that n is prime. However, I'm stuck on how to prove the latter is true assuming n is prime. I tried following the proof for Wilson's Theorem, but I'm not sure how to translate it into a proof for $(n-2)!$. Can anyone show me where to start?

Comment: Just use Wilson's theorem, and forget about its proof....

Comment: I haven't tried the proof yet but the way the problem is constructed seems to scream for induction, so I'd try induction.

Comment: DON"T DO INDUCTION!!!!!!!  There I screamed so hopefully the screams cancel out.  Not that if $p$ is prime then for any $k$ there is a unique $m\mod p$ so that $km \equiv 1 \mod p$.  And that will be it!  $(n-2)!$ is the product of all $k\mod p$ *except* $-1$ so for every $k$ the $k^{-1}$ will also be a term of the product. Except $-1$ (All that is left is showing $-1$ and $1$ are the only $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod n$ solutions.)